# How to create more than one matrix in a row using matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, indexing

I am trying to get a series of vectors which come from the same original, to make an easy example, suppose this vector `V= (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` (of course mine is bigger)

The first vector has to look like this:

```
R1=(1,3,5,7,9)= V(1:1:end) 
The second vector:
R2=(2,4,6,8,10)=V(2:1:end)
The third vector:
R3=(3,5,7,9)=V(3:1:end)
The fourth vector:
R4=(4,6,8,10)=V(4:1:end)
...
R8=(8,10)=V(8:1:end)
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there an easier way to get this result?
2. How can I know the total number of Ri vectors with `distance = 1` that can obtained from `V`?

Comment: How do you define the distance between two vectors? Plus, be careful, your Ri vectors aren't equal to your RHS's

Answer (score 0):

Use Matlab's cell object which can hold a vector in every cell.
Use a for loop to fill this cell object gradually.

Code example:

```
%initialize V
V= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
%initialize an empty cell of size [10,1]
R= cell(length(V)-2,1); 

%fill the cell
for ii=1:length(R)
   R{ii} = V(ii:2:end); 
end

%prints results
for ii=1:length(R)
   R{ii} 
end
```

Results (each row is a different vector):

```
 1     3     5     7     9
 2     4     6     8    10
 3     5     7     9
 4     6     8    10
 5     7     9
 6     8    10
 7     9
 8    10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot drorco, I did it but the cell array appears as if it were just one elements of the matrix. How can I make that all the numbers have one place of this R matrix?

Comment: `R` is columnar cell vector each containing row numeric vector. That's why you can have 'a sort of matrix' with missing elements. Each number is accessed by `R{ii}(jj)` adressing.

Comment: instead of R1,R2,R3...R8, the names of your vectors are now: R{1},R{2},R{3},...R{8}. For example, In order to access the j element of vector 1, write: R{1}(j)

Comment: How did you know that length(V)-2 was the appropiate size? why 2?

Comment: glad to help! I understood it from your example, 2 is the jump factor according to your question, so if the array contains N elements, there are only N-2 vectors which can be extracted in this matter. Do you see why?